# How to force Google maps marker to appear above a section layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im displaying a Google map that has a section layer above it.
Im having trouble with displaying Markers above the section layer(The blue layer in the attached image).

Layer 1 : Google Map
Layer 2: Section above the map - Hiding the map
Layer 3 : Markers

I tried playing with marker settings including zIndex property but it doesnt work.
How can i make it work?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <section id="gMap"></section>
        <section id="gMapOverlay"></section>
        <section id="droppableChest"></section>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
        zoom : 13,
        center : myLatlng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : myLatlng,
        map : map,
        optimized: false,
        zIndex: 9999
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[image]

Comment: Why are people voting this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add said div `gMapOverlay` inside the map DOM containers ([MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapPanes)). Specifically one that lies below the markers as is the case with the `overlayLayer`.

To grab a reference to the MapPanes you must instance an [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView) and create `draw` and `onAdd` methods for it. The latter is called when the OverlayView is added to the map, so it suits your use case just fine:

```
var map, overlay;

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
        zoom : 13,
        center : myLatlng
    });

    map.Overlay= new google.maps.OverlayView();

    map.Overlay.draw = function () {};

    map.Overlay.onAdd=function() {
        var gMapOverlay = document.createElement("section");
        gMapOverlay.innerHTML = "new div";
        gMapOverlay.id="gMapOverlay";
        this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(gMapOverlay);
    };

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:myLatlng, 
        optimized: false, 
        map:map
    });

    map.Overlay.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This means your initial DOM has only gMap and droppableChest sections.